# Run tests from maven zip assembly

Tags: testing, maven, zip, maven-assembly-plugin

I have finally succeeded in getting Maven to zip together a bunch of jars using an assembly file and install it to my local repository.  That was difficult enough...

Now my goal is to configure another maven project so that when I do "mvn test", it will pull in that zip, unpack it, and run tests from the jars within that zip file.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is the POM for the assembly project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.pason</groupId>
<artifactId>RigFocusOnDataHub</artifactId>
<name>RigFocusOnDataHub</name>
<version>12.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<dependencies>
    ...
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>RigFocusOnDH.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>zip</id>
                    <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <!-- append to the packaging phase. -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                        <!-- goals == mojos -->
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is the POM for the second project.  Unfortunately, instead of downloading the zip file for RigFocusOnDataHub, it just fetches the jars for all of RigFocusOnDataHub's dependencies from the local repo.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.pason</groupId>
<artifactId>RigFocusDHSystemTest</artifactId>
<version>12.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pason</groupId>
        <artifactId>MurphyRigFocus</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pason</groupId>
        <artifactId>RigFocusOnDataHub</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack</id>
                    <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.pason</groupId>
                                <artifactId>MurphyRigFocus</artifactId>
                                <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                                <type>test-jar</type>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/tests/MurphyRigFocus</outputDirectory>
                            </artifactItem>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.pason</groupId>
                                <artifactId>RigFocusOnDataHub</artifactId>
                                <version>12.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                                <type>zip</type>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/tests/MurphyRigFocus</outputDirectory>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <testClassesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/tests/MurphyRigFocus</testClassesDirectory>
                <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports/MurphyRigFocus</reportsDirectory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*IT.*</include>
                </includes>
                <argLine>-Djava.library.path=${basedir}/target/classes/</argLine>
                <forkMode>pertest</forkMode>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Why not just do the test as part of the build cycle (before the big .jar is assembled)?

Comment: It sounds like you need to have a multi-module build with a separate integration-test module which handles all the integration test stuff.

Comment: You try to use the maven-surefire-plugin to run integration tests which is not the intention of the maven-surefire-plugin. For integration tests use the maven-failsafe-plugin.

Comment: Well, we want to test from the zip so that we can make sure we test exactly what will get deployed, just in case any of the modules get changed after we package everything (into a .zip, not a .jar)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to:

1. extract the jars from the zip - this is easy enough with maven-dependency-plugin
2. cut transitive dependencies so your jars don't end up in the path twice - you can do that at the source with maven-shade-plugin or in the test project itself with dependencies exclusions
3. add the jars to your test classpath, there are many ways to do that, I would try to use additional parameters in surefire configuration first